# How to use docker with NestjS apps

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, nestjs

I have a NestJS project with many apps, structure below:

```
my-project:
-- apps;
--- app-one
---- src
---- tsconfig.app.json
--- app-two
---- src
---- tsconfig.app.json
-- libs
-- package.json
-- etc...
```

I have two apps in one project: `app-one` and `app-two`, How to use docker to deploy `app-one` or `app-two`. When I have one app I know how to do this, I will create `Dockerfile` at the `package.json` directory and build/run, but how to do this with nested apps?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple Dockerfiles at your root with different filenames.

```
my-project:
-- apps;
--- app-one
---- src
---- tsconfig.app.json
--- app-two
---- src
---- tsconfig.app.json
-- libs
-- package.json
-- Dockerfile.app-one
-- Dockerfile.app-two
```

For the Dockerfiles, you just need to run your custom scripts to build the specified app

`Dockerfile.app-one`

```
FROM node:12.17-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /build
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .
RUN  yarn build:app-one

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start:app-one"]
```

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "build:app-one": "nest build app-one",
  "build:app-two": "nest build app-two",
  "start:app-one": "nest start app-one",
  "start:app-two": "nest start app-two",
}
```

`nest-cli.json`

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "app-one": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/app-one",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/app-one/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/app-one/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": []
      }
    },
    "app-two": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/app-two",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/app-two/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/app-two/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": []
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Then, specify the filename in your build/deploy tasks in your CI/CD

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image: docker:git

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build

build-app-one:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build . -f Dockerfile.app-one

build-app-two:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build . -f Dockerfile.app-two
```

If you need more informations, read the documentation about [monorepo architecture in NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have just one Dockerfile for all apps.

```
FROM node:18-alpine As build

ARG SERVICE_NAME

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN yarn build $SERVICE_NAME

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As production

ARG SERVICE_NAME
ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/apps/${SERVICE_NAME}/* .

USER node

CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

Then the docker build command would look like:

```
docker build -t <tag-name> --build-arg SERVICE_NAME=<nestjs-app-name> .
```